# Why is my SwiftUI List not being populating with all my data?

Tags: swift, list, api, swiftui

I have my data coming back from an api call using Combine this way:

```
[Animals.Dog(id: nil, name: "Bobby", age: 4), Animals.Dog(id: nil, name: "Cronos", age: 2), Animals.Dog(id: nil, name: "Willy", age: 2), Animals.Dog(id: nil, name: "Rex", age: 8)]
finished
```

When populating my List with the array of animals, only the first item is populated. But this same first item is displayed as much animals as they are. In this case, the first item is populated 4 times and I cannot see the three other dogs on my List.

Where are my data hidden?

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct AnimalsView: View {

  @State private var dogs = [Dog]()

  private let networkRequest = NetworkRequest()

  //MARK: - Body
  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
      TitleView()

      //MARK: Dogs list view
      List(dogs) {
        AnimalCell(name: $0.name,
                   age: $0.age)
      }
      .modifierViewList()
    }
    .onAppear {
      _ = networkRequest.downloadAnimals()
        .sink(receiveCompletion: {
          print($0)
        },receiveValue: { (animal) in
          self.dogs = animal.dogs
          print(animal.dogs)
        })
    }
  }
}

//MARK: Network request
extension NetworkRequest {
  func downloadAnimals() -> AnyPublisher<Animal, Error> {
    URLSession.shared
      .dataTaskPublisher(for: EndPoint.rates.url)
      .receive(on: networkQueue)
      .map(\.data)
      .decode(type: Animal.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
      .mapError { (error) -> NetworkRequest.Error in
        switch error {
        case is URLError:
          return Error.addressUnreachable(EndPoint.rates.url)
        default:
          return Error.invalidResponse
        }
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Animal.Dog` conforms to `Identifiable`, all your data has the same `id`, namely `nil`. Therefore, `List` thinks you only have one distinct `Animal.Dog`, the first with `id` of `nil`. Try giving them actual `id`s.

Answer (score 0):

[Animals.Dog(id: 1, name: "Bobby", age: 4), Animals.Dog(id: 2, name: "Cronos", age: 2), Animals.Dog(id: 3, name: "Willy", age: 2), Animals.Dog(id: 4, name: "Rex", age: 8)]

Comment: The best way was to declare my struct of Dog with let id = UUID() instead of let id: Int?